# Jquery Remove php code from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that contains php code I am trying to find a way to remove the php code from the string.

```
text = '<?php // This is a test sample ?> This is a description';
text.replace(/\<\?.*\?\?\>/, "");
```

I am not the best with regex. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's your true goal here? did you write a php app and are wanting to remove unsafe code that is being eval'd by javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very naive approach (assuming php code will have no ternary operator, and inner comments will have no question symbol, ;)):

```
var s = '<?php // This is a test sample ?> This is a description'
s.replace(/<\?php\s*[^\?]+\s*\?>/g, '')
// output: " This is a description"
```

Answer (score -2):

the php will execute before the javascript ever gets a chance to do it's thing on the php code.  You can't use javascript to change php code.  (Although it does work the other way around.)